# Is there any way to log info from a Flutter app without launching it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have configured my Flutter app to receive notifications from somewhere.

I want to log info to know how the `backgroundHandler` executes.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, the problem is that when you reduce your app, the emulator disconnect with your app and you can't log anything without relaunching your app, right ?

If that's the case, you can just plug a real android device and launch your app on it, you'll be able to reduce your app without disconnecting VSC or Android Studio.

Comment: I want to log related to the app when it's not running, basically I want to see what happens when it receives a notification.